# Products are not showing in storefront search page

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I have installed fresh sitecore commerce in my local machine. After installation when I browse search page, It doesnt show me any products. I have verified all products are under catalog in sitecore content tree. I also performed sitecore indexing several time. But No luck. Looks like those are not getting indexed. Its default storefront. I havent made any changes in it yet.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using SXA Storefront there are two SXA templates that impact the storefront search for catalog content `_Searchable` and `_SearchableWithoutRelatedItems`. To include a product in SXA search results, you must reference this template. Without it, Sitecore does not include page nor catalog content in the SXA-specific computed field sxacontent.

[image]

You can take a look at the sitecore documentation on configuring search for SXA storefront https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/configuring-site-searches-in-sxa-storefront.html

Comment: Thanks Cristi for response. This is already set in my local sitecore. But still not working.

Comment: You have also configured Sitecore/Storefront/Settings/Site Grouping/Storefront to use the SXA indexes like described https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/walkthrough--including-commerce-catalog-items-in-sxa-indexes.html? Or you are using the default sitecore indexes?

Comment: I am using default sitecore indexes

Answer (score 0):

When installing sitecore commerce, sometime installation of default storefront fails but commerce installation continues.

So try adding new site. Below is the link for adding new tenant and site in sitecore commerce
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/create-a-commerce-tenant-and-site.html

After creating new site, configure your new storefront using power shell toolbox "SXA Site Manager". Refer below link to configure
https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/configure-your-storefront.html

[image: SXA Site Manager]

Then verify product listing page.